# Show that $(1 2 3)(4 5 6 7)$ has order $12$. What is the order of $(1 2 3)(3 7 6 5)?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

I understand that the order is the LCM of $3$ and $4$ which is $12$, but I don't know how to show this with actual cycles or permutations. I am not looking for a formal proof just clarification on the whole concept.

Comment: Can you express it in the standard form as a product of disjoint cycles.

Comment: The short version is that the order of a permutation is the LCM of the lengths of the cycles appearing in a disjoint cyclic representation of the permutation.  $(123)(4567)$ is a permutation in a disjoint cyclic representation of itself and so fits this pattern.  $(12\color{red}{3})(\color{red}{3}765)$ however is not in a disjoint cyclic representation since the $3$ is repeated.  Rewrite this second permutation in a disjoint cyclic representation in order to utilize the alluded to theorem.

Comment: If your question is *why* the alluded to theorem is true, then contrary to what you state in your question you *should* be wanting a formal proof of this.  If you needed clarification on the *definitions themselves*... what it means to have order $12$ or what a disjoint cyclic decomposition of a permutation is, or even how to read and interpret the permutation $(123)(3765)$... then you need to rephrase your question specifying what of these is needed.  All of this however should already be included in any introductory text on the matter.

Comment: Thank you, and I need clarification on what the order 12 actually looks like. My grad class is remote, and this concept is not clicking with me. We don't use a text, just lecture notes, and none of the books I have downloaded really gives a good explanation other than it is the LCM of the cycle lengths. So what does this look like with numbers? Are the 12 elements different arrangements of (1 2 3 4 5 6 7)?

Comment: "*Are the 12 elements different arrangements of (1 2 3 4 5 6 7)*?"  Letting $\sigma = (123)(4567)$ you have the twelve elements are $\sigma, \sigma^2, \sigma^3, \sigma^4,\dots, \sigma^{12}$ where "exponentiation" here is with respect to function composition (*permutation "multiplication"*).  $\sigma^2$ for instance is $(132)(46)(57)$ and $\sigma^{12} = ()$ the identity permutation.

Comment: I worry that your saying "different arrangements of (1234567)" might imply that you don't understand the significance of the cyclic notation here.  $\sigma^2$ that I wrote above is the permutation mapping $1$ to $3$, mapping $3$ to $2$, mapping $2$ to $1$, mapping $4$ to $6$ and mapping $6$ to $4$, etc...  Written in two-line notation that is $\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4&5&6&7\\3&1&2&6&7&4&5\end{pmatrix}$.  If you were to interpret a permutation as the second line in a two-line notation, yes they are all different arrangements of $1234567$... though the cyclic notation is in my opinion superior.

Comment: As for what "order 12 looks like" it means that $\sigma^1,\sigma^2,\dots,\sigma^{11}$ are all different than the identity permutation while $\sigma^{12}$ is exactly equal to the identity permutation and thus implies that $\sigma^i = \sigma^{12k+i}$ for any integers $i$ and $k$.